# C#: Barcode to byte array to valid zip file

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, zip, pdf417

I'm scaning a Pdf417 barcode which returns me a byte[] array. The DataString itself is a cryptic value like face to keyboard multiple times and fast. So I'm guessing it could be a zip file which is stored in the barcode. In the zip file there should be a xml file.
I had different attempts so far to convert my byte[] array to a valid zip file. In the end I was never able to open said zip file.
The barcodes are created by certified software solutions, so the barcode is not the problem for sure.
I can't be the only one who has had this problem, right?

Output when reading a barcode with dummy data in it:

> "\0\0\0\vz\0\u0002B\u0001\u0002PK\u0003\u0004\n\0\0\0\b\0 E\u0081Q|\u0015\u00163Î\u0001\0\0\u0004\u0004\0\0\u0004\0\0\0txab}SMo£0\u0010½ï¯°|\a\u001bª¤Ý\u0015Påc\u0093Fê&\b²9ôÆÂ$ \r¦²M\u0093üûNø\b$Që\u008bí7ï½\u0019{lçù\u0098ïÉ\aH\u0095\u0015Â¥\u0096É)\u0001\u0011\u0017I&v.ý»\u009e\u0019OôÙsÖ\u0004iB¹4Õúý\u0017c\u0087ÃÁT\u0087L©\u0004b3N\u0099\u008aSÈ#¦\u0012fs>ä6·X\u0018í#y\u009aB\u008cS¤Ñ}}\u001c\u008d)\t\u0017S\u0097ÎV+\\u009dÔ¦^z?\b\u000egRäï\u00918\u0091\u0097À\b&Æ2ÊÁ¥/\u0091Pä\u000fd ÉhNÉÛÂwé\u0013ç\u009c²Fäcé\u0085XLÉk¤´¨4\u0015\u009d\u0092Y&[äìÒ\u0017×ÚJ\u001fn\u008cQh,¥÷8\u0018\u009a\u0016\u000eÓÆa>ütØ%Tgbmªf\u001fö\0\u0094\u0015I\aTàV\u0016¹gãe\u0018|`pËa\u0015pÍ)\u0085Îö5É²\u008d\a$ÕHgÍn½\u009d\u0005ö'\ao\u0080'á&ç\u000ek\u0080\u008e1\u0093Ø>\u0018\u0083\u0080m¦\u0015ëEV:\u0005Ù\u0006njYÃQ{ãB\u0094ÊaÕú:\u001c\u0096¹g]r\u009ew½"¿ðuæ²Pª©ox\u0011÷Ñ\u008e;ÞÌ\u008dWß7&\u0085Ð2ûW\u009e\u001fÍM\r\u0001ìJ|Oxa\u008dS\v\ÓüRÆi¤ ª·â]\u0090^Íßçs\u0096 Û\u009b~lm:¬ãM!)ã³v¤Ã\u0002Óô²Þ\u0087:Ù$\u008dä\u000eTPî\u0081ÝÃ7\aú½Ý\u0002\u001a}\QÙ\u001d·nï×Ý\u000fð\u0093Êÿí×aø\u0082±ÓÞ'PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\0\n\0\0\0\b\0 E\u0081Q|\u0015\u00163Î\u0001\0\0\u0004\u0004\0\0\u0004\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0txabPK\u0005\u0006\0\0\0\0\u0001\0\u0001\02\0\0\0ð\u0001\0\0\0\0"

Dont pay too much attention to this function, at this stage I'm probably trying too much to get to a solution. This is just one of many test voids of mine.

```
public void Test(byte[] bytes)
    {
        byte[] zipBytes;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test");
                using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                {
                    entryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            zipBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\BarcodeReaderTesting\test.zip", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            fileStream.Write(zipBytes, 0, zipBytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Any tips on this topic?

Comment: `I'm guessing it could be a zip file which is stored in the barcode` That seems somewhat of a leap... What leads you to that conclusion? What is the origin of the bar code? The meaning of it would have to be documented somewhere surely?

Comment: What are the first few bytes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: The barcode is on a salary document and contains data which is on the document anyways. Its purpose is faster machine reading i guess. I come to the conclusion it being a zip because if i scan selfmade barcodes or Pdf417 from the internet I have no problem to get the DataString.
I found some instructions but they were not clear to me. It's in german tho. But it says something about data as xml in a zip with info-zip format, the name of the zip-entry is "txab", the zip file itself is called txab and the file extension .zip was renounced for space reasons.

Comment: About the first few bytes: every barcode starts with different bytes, which means they are encrypted in some way, right?

Comment: If the first few bytes are different every time, it's not a zip archive.

Comment: maybe its a base-64 encoded version of the expected xml. it might as well use reversible encryption where you're probably out of luck without a key. care to post an example of a test byte sequence you're allowed to publicly disclose? there are many german speakers here including me, add relevant parts of those instructions you mentioned earlier.

Comment: also, re your code sample, I guess you're holding it wrong :) that code would compress the input, not extract something from it.

Comment: I also don't understand what the code in your question is trying to do: it's taking the byte array which you suspect is a zip, and then creating a new zip archive, creating a new file in that zip archive, and putting the content that you suspect is a zip as a new file called "test"

Comment: My code snippet is just  things i tried. Don't pay too much attention to that. I'm lost and probably trying to many things to get to a solution.
I cant post all of the returning datastring cause it's too long. But I'll edit my question with it.

Comment: If you think the bytes actually is a zip file, just write it directly to a file, don't do all the muckery around with the ZipArchive, just remove the entire contents of your method and replace it with `File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\BarcodeReaderTesting\test.zip", bytes);`

Comment: I already tried that, it creates the zip file but I can't open the zip due to not being valid. I probably have to rethink the hole process and try to find a solution without reading the barcode.